# Display:none em Modal e @media afeta SEO

Tags: css, seo, layout-responsivo, display

Estou tentando aplicar a responsividade em um site, porém alguns menus de categorias eu transfiro para dentro de uma modal do bootstrap que utiliza o display:none, além de estar fazendo com que alguns elementos do desktop sejam ocultados para que apareçam outros elementos no mobile, também utilizando display:none dentro de @media (ex: @media(max-width: 767px)).

Gostaria de saber o impacto dessa questão no SEO do site, se é preferível que ao invés do display:none eu coloque position:absolute; left: -10000px !important; opacity: 0;

Desde já agradeço a atenção e peço desculpa se não fui claro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arenas, de acordo com o próprio google. [Link aqui](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en)

> Texto e links ocultos
>   Ocultar texto ou links em seu conteúdo para manipular as classificações de pesquisa do Google pode ser visto como enganoso e é uma violação das Diretrizes para webmasters do Google . O texto (como palavras-chave excessivas) pode ser oculto de várias maneiras, incluindo:
>
> Usando texto branco sobre um fundo branco
>   Localizando texto atrás de uma imagem
>   Usando CSS para posicionar o texto fora da tela
>   Configurando o tamanho da fonte para 0
>   Ocultar um link apenas vinculando um caractere pequeno - por exemplo, um hífen no meio de um parágrafo
>   Ao avaliar seu site para ver se ele inclui texto ou links ocultos, procure por algo que não seja facilmente visualizável pelos visitantes de seu site. Há algum texto ou links apenas para mecanismos de pesquisa em vez de visitantes?
>
> No entanto, nem todo texto oculto é considerado enganoso. Por exemplo, se seu site inclui tecnologias que os mecanismos de pesquisa têm dificuldade de acessar, como JavaScript, imagens ou arquivos Flash, o uso de texto descritivo para esses itens pode melhorar a acessibilidade do seu site. Lembre-se de que muitos visitantes humanos que usam leitores de tela, navegadores móveis, navegadores sem plug-ins e conexões lentas não poderão visualizar esse conteúdo e também se beneficiarão do texto descritivo. Você pode testar a acessibilidade do seu site desativando JavaScript, Flash e imagens no navegador ou usando um navegador somente de texto, como o Lynx . Algumas dicas para tornar seu site acessível incluem:
>
> Imagens: use o atributo alt para fornecer texto descritivo. Além disso, recomendamos o uso de legendas legíveis e texto descritivo ao redor da imagem. Veja este artigo para mais conselhos sobre como publicar imagens.
>   JavaScript: coloque o mesmo conteúdo do JavaScript em uma tag. Se você usar esse método, verifique se o conteúdo é exatamente igual ao que está contido no JavaScript e se esse conteúdo é exibido para os visitantes que não têm o JavaScript ativado no navegador.
>   Vídeos: inclua um texto descritivo sobre o vídeo em HTML. Você também pode considerar fornecer transcrições. Veja este artigo para mais conselhos sobre a publicação de vídeos.

Quanto a sua dúvida é correto sim utilizar display:none quando `@media screen and ()`, inclusive, ao utilizar a propriedade `position:absolute; left: -10000px !important; opacity: 0;` é considerado blackhat conforme texto acima:

> Usando CSS para posicionar o texto fora da tela

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu tinha lido este texto porém não havia conseguido interpretar da maneira correta, Obrigado pela ajuda!